# How to generate image from request servlet

Tags: java, image, base64, mms, mm7

http://www.wupload.com/file/2662484487/example.rar -- pls download this to see that string

I have string that contains imageId, imageName and image content.

First I substring it for only the image content (jpg format) and convert that image content to `Base64`, but when I convert `Base64` to image, I've got this error:

`not a jpeg file`

Any suggestion? I think problem is encoding...

Sorry for my English.

Comment: What is the source for your string? How do you come to know that the image content has started???

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you put the image content in a byte array instead in a string? I had a project once about compressing images and whenever I put the image content inside a string the byte arrangement of the image seems to change.